# How to call SharePoint API which uses ADFS/SAML as authentication or authorization

Tags: java, saml, adfs, rest-client

I have a very basic problem to share, I am working on a small piece of application which is reading data form SharePoint On-premise API. This API is recently moved to ADFS on premise for authentication and I need to make changes to our code for this authentication. I have already gone through the documentation and understand the SAML/ADFS architecture. Could anyone please guide me to the Sample Java client code to server this purpose?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I have very vague information. I need to start from scratch and want to understand what are the basic steps or any library I could use to authenticate my Java API with on-premise SharePoint which is using ADFS and SAML 2.0 authentication.